# Why is TextArea Empty on jqGrid Edit Form

Tags: java, jquery, jqgrid

I have attempted to update jqGrid from 4.6.0 to 4.13.3.

When I do Edit Forms that are based on grids that contain textarea inputs display empty even though the cells do have content.

Comment: Add a sample code or jsfiddle link.

Comment: the best way to solve the problem is providing the demo, which uses non-minimized version (`jquery.jqgrid.src.js`) and which reproduces the reported problem. In any way you should include JavaScript code, which you use, in the text of your question.

Comment: I will try and put a demo together. In the interim I rolled jqGrid back to 4.6.0.